# Why is the forward fairing of the pylon very shiny and metallic in appearance in A350?

Tags: engine, feature-identification, airbus-a350, nacelle, engine-pylon

One can notice the forward fairing of pylon is very shiny and metallic. This is quite unique and I do not find it in other aircraft. Why is this?

Does it serve any specific aerodynamic purpose or does it house any anti-icing provisions?

[image: a350 zoomed in]

Comment: I don't really know the answer but if you note, all the other "leading edge" surfaces on the A350 are unpainted.  That part appears to be a leading edge also.  The nose is not a painted metal object but rather a plastic radome that likely has the color embedded in it.  My theory is that they leave these unpainted so that you don't get a ragged effect as the paint wears or chips off over time.

Comment: It is definitely the [first panel of the engine pylon](http://www.nycaviation.com/newspage/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/IMG_7208.jpg) and is indeed left unpainted. Would be interesting to know why.

Comment: @757toga from [this picture](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/95938/why-is-the-forward-fairing-of-the-pylon-very-shiny-and-metallic-in-appearance-in#comment264728_95938) it seems to be riveted.

Comment: It's not heated. It's probably made of a material that is difficult to obtain paint adhesion, say titanium or some grade of stainless, or doesn't need paint because it's a corrosion resistant material and they are saving a few ounces, or some other reason known only to insiders.

Comment: @JohnK: that's titanium, right. Is it really difficult to be painted? The Blackbird was definitely painted  :)

Comment: Titanium requires elaborate processes to get paint to stick, acid etching, sometimes sandblasting.  They may just leave the paint off BECAUSE it's titanium or stainless (more likely) so they can leave it unpainted without worrying about corrosion.

Comment: It is also specifically covered during manufacturing: https://www.flickr.com/photos/131621852@N02/33312795343/

Answer (score 1):

You figured it out when you wrote the question. It's because the engine nacelles are equipped with anti-icing heaters powered by air from a compressor port, and painting those areas would be counter-productive. Same with the inboard sections of the wings.

Comment: Are you saying that the small square dark area pointed out by the OP functions as an engine nacelle anti-ice heater?

Comment: @757toga No, I am saying that it has a heater for anti-ice. There appears to be a NACA scoop just forward of that in the nacelle design for the -1000.

Comment: According to the ice and rain protection scheme for the A350-900, with respect to the engine and wing protection, the engine nacelles' air intake (lips of the nacelles) and slats 3, 4 and 5 (outboard of the engines) can be heated (for anti-ice) by bleed air.

Comment: Can you update with relevant sources @JuanJimenez? I tried to look up and found what @757toga says is correct. I cannot find any pylon heaters but only nacelle heaters. https://www.smartcockpit.com/docs/a350-900-flight-deck-and-systems-briefing-for-pilots.pdf

Comment: You won't get ice accretion on  areas like that unless it's runback ice and cowls are usually evaporative heating to prevent that. The A350 anti-ice system description doesn't mention a heated panel.

Comment: My use of terminology was unclear. There are no electric heaters there, it's all heated with hot air from a compressor port. I believe this patent from GE: https://patents.google.com/patent/US5088277A/en explains how the anti-icing system not only heats the ring around the cowling but also the plate in question.

Comment: @JuanJimenez But the A350 is powered by RR Trent XWB, *not* GE engines. I haven't seen this part unpainted on other RR Trent engines, or any GE engines for that matter.

Comment: Although the A350 uses RR engines and your reference to the engine anti-ice patent is for GE engines could you extract that portion of the patent that applies to the plate in question and add it to your answer? Thanks

Comment: Patents can be licensed so who owns the patent is irrelevant. The reference in the patent is anything that mentions Figure 2 or item 16.

Comment: The patent does NOT show the shiny metal plate on the pylon being heated. Fig 2 is a cross-section of the inlet cowl at the 12 o'clock position. I believe the drawing is being mistaken for a drawing of the forward end of the pylon. Accordingly, Item 16 is the outer wall of the inlet cowl, not the shiny plate of interest.